# Inspect element with pseudo-class in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging, pseudo-class

I'm looking for a method to inspect elements styled using pseudo-classes (such as `:hover`) from IE.

I am able to do this with Firefox using the Firebug HTML style drop-down that allows the browser to apply a pseudo-class to a selected element:

[image]

I am also able to do this in Chrome by toggling the element state:

[image]

However, I have not been able to find a similar option with IE developer tools. I've tried using [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/), but the same option that is present in Firefox does not seem to be in the Lite version.

Is there a way to apply pseudo-classes to elements in IE (similar to Firefox and Chrome) so that I may see how it's being styled, or otherwise observe pseudo-class styling in IE?

Comment: +1 I've been looking for that feature in Firefox for a while now. Can't believe I never noticed the drop-down arrow on the Style tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never found this in the native developer tools included with IE.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't found anything in IE developer tools either, and was hoping there was some other option out there that I've never heard of but would do the job. I'll mark this as the answer for now, since it doesn't seem like what I'm looking for exists at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. It's now almost 4 years later on this answer so of course the developer tools will have changed.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like IE 11 has this feature now, although it seems like it's only for Hover (and Visited for anchor tags).

[image]